# Adding code to child theme function.php via my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am developing a plugin that needs to overwrite the hook to the parent style.css.

I use the plugin to dequeue the style from the child theme but then I need to enqueue another file into it so that the child theme css works. Not sure if I am making sense.

Basically how would I go about adding this code into the child theme functions.php via my plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', plugins_url( '/plugin/css/3.0.31' ) . '/style.min.css' );
}
```

As it is a plugin it would need to do it automatically without access to the file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! So once you've dequeued the child's style, I think all you'd have to do is enqueue your own stylesheet, using the same identifier as the style you just dequeued... To be safe, use the same dependency array too...

Comment: Thanks @MacPrawn I did try that but it didnt work - must of missed a bit of code..

Tried again and works.. Thanks for the help :D